# D3 - Remove padding to have graph fill the page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm a bit stuck trying to remove the padding on this graph. The SVG seems to correctly take up the available space, however the "G" inside the SVG is smaller. What I am after is the "G" inside the SVG to take up the whole body area as well.

I thought it would be simple, for example just setting the below code to 0 instead. However that forces things to be off the page.

```
// 2. Use the margin convention practice 
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
```

Can anyone help me to get the graph fitting the body height and width please?

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/wkjx1c38/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set margins to `0` graph is fitting the body height and width. The problem is in axis labels and ticks:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
```

You are moving axis under the graph. If I were you I would change margins to minimum value that still allows axes ticks and labels to fit on page. Alternatively you can try to change width and height of the graph based on axes size, but I expect it to be painful and not worth the effort.

So I would just:

```
margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 35,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 30
}
```

There is also another solution - change your axes labels and position them inside graph - then you can change margins to `0` and still have description visible.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your reply. The trouble is this causes issues when the number scale changes for example if the number becomes 1234 instead of 0.6. I've marked it as accepted though.

Comment: I thought about it a little today. If you implement some kind of resize logic to fit visualization in the window on resizes(like here https://bl.ocks.org/curran/3a68b0c81991e2e94b19). Then you can use `document.querySelector('.y.axis').getBoundingClientRect().width + 5` to get proper value for left margin. You also can trigger one mock resize manually after graph renders and have nice left margin. By analogy it's possible to fix x axis. I haven't ever tried it, but it looks like an option.